# Auto jump script

Tags: python

I can't find anything on how to make an a button press execute when a number is got after it has been randomly generated

i need the space button to be pressed in a reandom amount of time(around 1min)

```
import random
import msvcrt
msvcrt.getch()
b'a'

upper_limit = 47
lower_limit = 6
print("Low numb:", lower_limit)
print("Up numb:", upper_limit)
range_of_nums = range(lower_limit, upper_limit)
number = random.choice(range_of_nums)
print("Numb:", number)

while True:
    key = msvcrt.getch().lower()
    if key == b'a':
        print("You've pressed A. I'll now do the thing I'm supposed to do when you press A.")
```

i have tried this, but i don't have a msvcrt module, and most probably it won't even work, please help.

Comment: `msvcrt` is only available on Windows.

Comment: If you want something more portable, try the [`keyboard`](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) library.